# How should I go about proving this identity?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

Found this on a math worksheet but wasn't able to prove it.

$$4(\cos^6x+\sin^6x)=1+3\cos^2(2x)$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the LHS of this equation, we can lower the exponent as follow:

$4(cos^6( x) +sin^6( x ) )= 4(cos^{2\cdot 3}(x) + sin^{2\cdot 3}(x) )= 4[(\dfrac{1+cos(2x)}{2})^3+(\dfrac{1-cos(2x)}{2})^3] = 4 \cdot \dfrac{2 + 2 cos^2(2x) + 4 cos^2(2x)}{2^3}= 4 \cdot \dfrac{2 + 6cos^2(2x)}{8} = \dfrac{2 + 6 cos^2(2x)}{2} = 1 + 3cos^2(2x)$

So we get $4(cos^6( x) +sin^6( x ) )= 1 + 3cos^2(2x)$ as wanted.

Comment: Note that between the second and third line I simply developed and reduce the 3rd degree identity.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm stuck on how cos^(2*3)x and sin^(2*3)x from the first form turns into ((1+cos(2x))/2)^3 + ((1-cos(2x))/2)^3 in the second form.

Comment: @WeirdBishop it is a well know identity, to lower the $^2$ exponent. Just look up « $cos^2(x)$ simplification » and you will find a quick proof of it

Answer (score 2):

You can set $u=e^{ix}$

$4(\cos^6 x+\sin^6 x)=\frac 4{64}\Big((u+\frac 1u)^6-(u-\frac 1u)^6\Big)=\frac 1{16}\times 2\times(6u^4+20+\frac 6{u^4})$

In the binomial dev $1,6,15,20,15,6,1$ you get to keep and double only $6,20,6$ the other terms are cancelling each other due to sign.

$=\frac 18\Big(6(u^2+\frac 1{u^2})^2+8\Big)=1+\frac34(u^2+\frac 1{u^2})^2=1+3\cos(2x)^2$